# Bash 'cd' with cdable_vars: how to suppress CWD echo?

Tags: bash, cd-command, shopt

I have used the Bash `shopt cdable_vars` option for years. When I `cd` to a destination that requires `cdable_vars` to resolve, the shell echoes my CWD before returning me to the prompt. When I `cd` to a destination that *doesn't* require a `cdable_vars` lookup (i.e. a correct, fully spelled subdirectory or an absolute path), the shell doesn't echo my CWD.

Is this the normal, (undocumented?) behavior of `cdable_vars`?

I faintly recall having activated this behavior at one point, because I liked being reminded that I had navigated to a cdable_var. Now I don't want it, but I can't figure out how to turn it off.

I use the `cd` builtin (no function or alias).

I do use a prompt command hook, but running with `set -x` shows that both the `cd` command and the echo happen before the prompt command runs.

Other places to look?

Comment: Is your `CDPATH` variable set?

Comment: No, the CDPATH environment variable isn't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deal with this with the following ugly hack:

```
$ type -a cd
cd is aliased to `cd $1 >/dev/null'
cd is a shell builtin
```

In other words, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias cd='cd >/dev/null'
```

Comment: Evidently this *is* the default behavior, and my memory of having activated it is wrong.

Comment: @Chap I don't think so. At least, I couldn't reproduce this on my system (Arch, bash, version 4.4.12(1)). And yes, I did remove the alias before testing ;). I'm guessing you've also turned something else on (that's why I asked about `CDPATH`) but I can't think of what it might be.